# Notation of the square (or other power) of a function $f(x)$

Tags: functions, soft-question, notation

How do you notate the square (or other power) of a function $f(x)$?
Is it $f^2(x)$ (similar to $\sin^2(x)$ for example), $f(x)^2$ or do you have to use $(f(x))^2$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The standard way to write this is $f(x)^2$ (this always means $(f(x))^2$ rather than $f(x^2)$, so you don't have to worry about any ambiguity).  You will occasionally see $f^2(x)$, but I would not recommend this--$f^2(x)$ more often means $f(f(x))$.   The notation $f^2(x)$ for squaring $f(x)$ is generally used for only a few particular functions (typically ones that you might often want to square and whose argument is often written without parentheses), such as trigonometric functions and $\log x$.

Comment: If $f^2(x)=f(f(x))$ then what is $f^{-2}(x)$? Is it the inverse of $f^{-1}=g$ squared, i.e. $g(g(x))$

Comment: Yes, that would be the most common meaning.

Answer (score 2):

Square of a function $f(x)$ can be denoted as $f^2(x)$, similar to $sin^2x$ and $cos^2x$.

Comment: Yes, it could be denoted by that, but in some contexts one might want that notation to mean something different.  The best advice is to use a convenient notation but *define* the use of it in anything approaching a formal presentation.  Readers will be better served that way.