# Probability of 2 people going to the same room

Tags: probability

There are $2$ people and $\frac{n}{lg(n)}$ rooms.

We will pick these $2$ people and put them in random rooms (which can be the same).

In the universe of possibilities, what is the chance of them to be in the same room?

---

What I thought: if there are $\frac{n}{\lg(n)}$ rooms, the probability of them to be in the same room is 
$$
\left(\frac{n}{\lg(n)}\right)^{-1} \times \left(\frac{n}{\lg(n)}\right)^{-1} \times \frac{n}{\lg(n)} = \frac{\lg(n)}{n}.
$$
Does that mean that from all $\frac{n^2}{\lg^2(n)}$ possibilities, $\frac{\lg(n)}{n}\%$ of it are choices where they go to the same room?

Comment: If it matters, $lg(n) = log_2(n)$.

Comment: so only an integer value of rooms if n is a multiple of it's lg ?

Comment: If you think this matters, you can consider there are $\lceil \frac{n}{lg(n)} \rceil$ rooms, but I think it doesn't.

Comment: It technically matters if there's a whole number of rooms, or that a function result squared, doesn't necessary have the same notation as an iterated function.https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1861580/notation-of-the-square-or-other-power-of-a-function-fx But I'll leave it at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, we need to check that $n$ is such that $M=\frac{n}{\log_2(n)}$ is a positive integer. Such $n$ exists (for instance let $n=2^{2^{k}}$ for $k$ a positive integer).

Now I will assume the rooms are chosen uniformly at random (each with the same probability). In this case, the placement of the first person is arbitrary, only the placement of the second person matters. Once the first guest walks into their room, the probability of the second guest walking into the same room is $\frac{1}{M}=\frac{\log_2(n)}{n}$. Since the first guest was in an arbitrary room, the probability of both guests ending up in the same room is just that, $\frac{1}{M}$.

Comment: So it means that in the universe of possibilities ($M^2$ possibilities), $\frac{1}{M} \times M^2$ is the number of possibilities in which they stay in the same room?

Comment: Yes. which is equal to the number of rooms I might add.